# How to define an environment variable in Azure devOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to use an environment variable to connect the GEE API in my tests. I would like this environment variable to be available in all runner OS. In github actions I would do the following:

```yaml
env:
  EARTHENGINE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.EARTHENGINE_TOKEN_VAR }}
```

And an env variable called `EARTHENGINE_TOKEN` will be added to every downstream runner. Can I do the same in ADO ? I tried using parameter but they are not set as env variables:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: EARTHENGINE_TOKEN
    value: $(EARTHENGINE_TOKEN_VAR)
```

where `EARTHENGINE_TOKEN_VAR` is saved as a variable in pipeline definition

Comment: ``` env:
    EARTHENGINE_TOKEN: $(EARTHENGINE_TOKEN_VAR)```

Comment: your solution is returning: "/.azure/unit.yaml (Line: 20, Col: 1): Unexpected value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipeline variables are mapped to env variables automatically so no need to extra work. There is only one exception - secrets. You must mapped them explicitly in each step as oposed to github actions that can map secret aat global level.

```yaml
steps:
- script: echo $EARTHENGINE_TOKEN
  env:
    EARTHENGINE_TOKEN: $(EARTHENGINE_TOKEN_VAR)
```